# how to get the echo statements as well as execution status from a shell script into a c++ program

Tags: c++, bash, popen

I have a shell script like:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "my string"
return 1
```

And I have a c++ code where I want both the echo statement(s) as well as the exec status.
I found some examples where we can use `popen()` or `system()` both the ways serves one requirement, but not both. Any suggestions how to do this?

Comment: Did those same examples showed you how to use `pclose()`? Do you know how to use `pipe`(), `fork()`, and `exec()`?

Answer (score 0):

`fork()` + `exec()` would be a pretty standard way to run another executable (*please* don't *ever* use `system()`, it's a security *nightmare*). To obtain the standard out / standard error stream output from the spawned process, the parent process would set up `pipe`s to connect to those streams and read them. As for the exit code, that you can get via `waitpid()` once the child process terminates (you'll get a SIG_CHILD signal, so make sure you have installed a signal handler for that).

I recommend a read through of [Advanced Programming in the UNIX Environment, 3rd Edition](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321637739).